# Outlook HTML email using media queries

Tags: css, email, outlook, html-email, font-size

I know most email clients are not fans of media queries but they do support them in a limited format.

All I am trying to do is alter the font size on one link .

```
<style type="text/css">
    .link {color: rgb(133, 16, 16); font-size: 24px;}

    @media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {            
        .link {font-size: 14px !important;}
    }
</style>

<a href="#" class="link">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

It works fine in a browser but not when emailed. Can anyone see anything i'm missing?

Comment: CSS in email is a totally different, old style only animal.

Comment: Cheers Rob, I've changed it to an image a allowed it to self scale - may as well save on a future headache...

Comment: What email environment are you using (client, version & device?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inline styles generally, because some email clients do not support `<style>` blocks.

Not sure what client/version/device you are using but that code can work on some.

However, consider inlining mobile-first, because that will cover Gmail IMAP, and then using min-width to cover the desktops. You'll also need something for Outlook Windows, since that doesn't accept `<style>` blocks, so here I'm using "mso-ansi-font-size" and that will take precedence over font-size for them.

This worked across all main emails:

```
<head> <!-- I needed to put a little bit of structure -->
<style type="text/css">
    
        @media only screen and (min-width: 420px) { <!-- Note this is for desktops -->   
            .link {font-size: 24px !important;}
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com.au" class="link" style="color: rgb(133, 16, 16); font-size: 14px;mso-ansi-font-size:24px;">DOWNLOAD</a> <!-- Note inlined; and Outlook alternative -->
</body>
```

If you do need to consider some really old desktop ISPs, some of which do not support `<style>` blocks, they will show the mobile version (14px). There is no way around it. But I prefer that than a desktop-first approach, because there are usually very few if any people on my lists that use old desktop ISPs, but a lot of people use Gmail IMAP (business accounts, typically).

For more on choosing mobile-first vs desktop-first approach for email, see https://htmlemailprinciples.com/third-precedent-of-practicality